# Queue Won't extract

Tags: c, pointers, queue, adt

I've got this C code. I've made a struct that simulates a queue (inserts in rear and extracts from front). Inserting seems to work, but when I want to delete a Node with this code, nothing happens.

```
nodo* dequeue(nodo* head) {
    if(head==NULL) {
        return NULL; //nothing to extract
    }
    else {
        nodo* temp=malloc(sizeof(nodo *));
        temp=head;
        head=head->next;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct coda{
 int x;
 char *y;
 char *t;
 int z;
 struct coda *next;
}nodo;
```

and here is the main

```
#include "list.h"

int main(void){
    nodo * testa;
    char* hi="hi";
    char* bye="bye";

    testa=enqueue(15,hi,bye,1,NULL);
    enqueue(16,hi,bye,1,testa);
    enqueue(17,hi,bye,1,testa);
    enqueue(18,hi,bye,1,testa);
    printList(testa);
    nodo *newHead = dequeue(&testa);
    printList(testa);
}
```

and the rest of the code

```
nodo* enqueue(int codArt,char *descrArt,char *indDest,int status,struct coda* head){

    if(head==NULL){
        nodo *nuovo_nodo=malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        nuovo_nodo->x=codArt;
        nuovo_nodo->y=descrArt;
        nuovo_nodo->t=indDest;
        nuovo_nodo->z=status;
        nuovo_nodo->next=NULL;
        return nuovo_nodo;
    }else if(head->next!=NULL)
        enqueue(codArt,descrArt,indDest,status,head->next);
    else
        head->next=enqueue(codArt,descrArt,indDest,status,head->next);

}

void printList(struct coda* head){
    struct coda* thead=head;
    while(thead!=NULL){

        printf("--> %d ",thead->codiceArticolo);
        thead=thead->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: yes, i'll add to the OP right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have provided seems to do the opposite of what you seem to require:

In `main` you have this call to `dequeue`:

```
nodo *newHead = dequeue(&testa);
```

Do you mean to return the old head?

Your `dequeue` function takes a pointer to the head.  It should be a pointer to a pointer.

You seem to be allocating memory in `dequeue`.  I now see an allocation is done in `enqueue` which is where it is supposed to happen. (btw when do you think you should deallocate memory?)

So, I think that dequeue should be more like this:

```
nodo* dequeue(nodo** head) {
    if(head==NULL) {
        return NULL; //nothing to extract
    }
    else {
        nodo* temp=*head;
        *head=temp->next;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I should have explained that the newHead was useless in that case, i just want the popped element to be returned to the main. Thank  you